# Can't open .AppImages even after setting it to executable?

Tags: executable

I've tried allowing execution in properties and opening through terminal but nothing works.

Specifically, I'm trying to install Linar Client for minecraft. I've tried launching through the desktop, files app, and terminal. It's enabled to be executed in properties. I'm expecting it to open and install the launcher, but nothing happens.

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Based on the info provided here there is nothing that can be used to offer any help. Please read this doc and edit the question with some details. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Specifically, we would need to know: i) what you are expecting, ii) how you attempt to open it, iii) what actually happens.

Comment: Hey @terdon, updated the post, if you could have a look that would be great.

Comment: It's not uncommon for people to assert that "nothing happens" when something besides expected behavior happens. At the command line, you should at the very least get an error message. Is is true that *absolutely nothing* happens?

Comment: I just downloaded the appimage and invoked it at the command line and it opens fine for me. I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.01. Is there a chance your download was corrupt? Did you try downloading the appimage again?

Comment: Hello @MDeBusk , upon redoing the commands, I realised I forgot about the error for installing libfuse2, so I did that, and my problem was fixed, sorry if I wasted your time, but thank you.

Comment: @BanjoTheBirb The missing libfuse2 is the most irritating things about running appimages in the latest release of Ubuntu. I'm glad you got it figured out.